# How to hide column in angular datatable excel export but show column on screen?

Tags: angular-datatables

I have this code to enable the excel export button:

```
self.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withButtons([
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Export to Excel',
            title: 'banana report'
        }]);
```

Previously I have used this code to hide the column in the datatable but have it show up in the excel:

```
self.dtColumnDefs = [
    DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(11).notVisible()
];
```

But how can I do the opposite? How can I hide in excel but not the datatable?

Answer (score 2):

Use **`exportOptions`**. For example

```js
.withButtons([
   {
    extend: 'excel',
    text: 'Export to Excel',
    title: 'banana report',
    exportOptions: {
      columns: [ 0, 1, 6, 7 ]
    }
   }])
```

Will only export the specifed column indexes. See

**https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html**
**https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/columns.html**